# Incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Facing below error when I run my selenium code using the IE driver. But the Same code works fine in chrome driver.

```
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
Jul 04, 2019 12:07:53 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such window' (400 expected)
```

I tried all possible solutions which usually occurs for IE like changing driver, zoom setting, disabling protected mode.